# ActionMailer template missing only on console and #deliver_later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am going a bit crazy with a Mailer.

i get the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template transaction_mailer/share_email with "mailer". Searched in: * transaction_mailer"
```

The mailer works correctly if from the controller i call:

```
TransactionMailer.share_email(params["email"], @contact).deliver_now
```

But if i run the same command from the console or i use #deliver_later i get the above error. I really cannot figure out why since everything seems ok also in the Mailer Preview!!

```
#mailers/transaction_mailer.rb
class TransactionMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def share_email email, contact
    @contact = contact
    mail to: email, subject: "#{contact.first_name} invites you"
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have a share_email.html.erb under view/transaction_mailer?

Comment: Yes, i do have share_email.html.erb and share_email.text.erb in the folder views/transaction_mailer
can't believe it!

Comment: You need to add a `from` parameter in the `mail to:`, like `mail to: email, from: "example@email.com", subject: "#{contact.first_name} invites you"`